# [ERROR]: Could not load 'plugins\test.jar' in folder 'plugins'

Tags: java, minecraft

minecraft paper server error
this is my yml code

api-version: 1.16
commands:
gamestart:
description: start
usage: /gamestart
rule:
description: rule
usage: /rule
main: testgroup.testartifact.Testartifact
name: Testartifact
version: "${project.version}"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that test.jar exists in the folder and it is valid.

Comment: i don't know what is problem

Comment: The problem is that you didn't make sure that test.jar exists in the folder and it is valid.